# PubSub vertx redis with event bus consumer after 3.7.0

Tags: redis, vert.x

We are migrating our Vertx code base from 3.6.3 to 3.8.1.

And I am not sure if the redis pub/sub and the event bus consumers still work together. I couldn't find any documentation in the new version either.

from the [3.5.1 documentation:](https://vertx.io/docs/3.5.0.Beta1/vertx-redis-client/java/)

```
vertx.eventBus().<JsonObject>consumer("io.vertx.redis.channel1", received -> {
  // do whatever you need to do with your message
  JsonObject value = received.body().getJsonObject("value");
  // the value is a JSON doc with the following properties
  // channel - The channel to which this message was sent
  // pattern - Pattern is present if you use psubscribe command and is the pattern that matched this message channel
  // message - The message payload
});

RedisClient redis = RedisClient.create(vertx, new RedisOptions());

redis.subscribe("channel1", res -> {
  if (res.succeeded()) {
    // so something...
  }
});
```

How does this work now with the new Redis client / RedisAPI?

[The documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-redis-client/java/#_pub_sub_mode) is not very descriptive. (There s not a subscribe command.. nor a trace of *channel1*)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to register a handler for subscriptions io.vertx.redis.client.Redis#handler. Which will be called with an io.vertx.redis.client.Response reference (with corresponding information) for published messages.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide sample code to show how it should be done. it improves your answer quality and make it more understandable.